# Fire extension on very page Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Google Chrome extension and want to autoload my extension on every new page, so that I can get the current url and check in a Database some data for it. I want to do it a bit like the adblockers and show how many ads where blocked with the badgetext. Anyway I don't get it workig to autoload on every new page I open. It loades once and then stays there. It only reloads when I click on the Icon to get the popup.html.

Here my Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Some name",
  "description": "Some desc.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "background"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

My background.js looks like this

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        // do some stuff with the new url
    });
});
```

Someone have a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use chrome.tabs API instead of chrome.windows API.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html

onCreated event and onUpdated event should work.

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function callback)

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function callback)

Comment: i will try as soon as i'm at home

Comment: working for now, loads on every pageload, but why does a badge update not trigger, but an normal alert ?